# Angular 4 landing page routing by user role

Tags: angular

What is the best way to route users to different landing page based on user role? While

What I am doing now: in the login component, I have a if-else and navigate to relevant page. However I have the same logic in registration page, and in the "home" button of various pages.

Is there any better way of doing the route by role that is more secured, such as within the router itself, without having to repeat the same logic all over the place?

```
      if (UserTypeEnum.TeacherUserType === userType.Value) {
        this.router.navigate(["/teacher-landing/"]);
      } else if (UserTypeEnum.StudentUserType === userType.Value) {
        this.router.navigate(["/student-landing"]);
      } else if (UserTypeEnum.AdminUserType === userType.Value) {
        this.router.navigate(["/admin-landing"]);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
      }
```

Or I could consolidate all these if-else in a single component, e.g. SecuredHome, and uses a default route to this SecuredHome.

Any recommendations for better design for secured and better scalability for different user role to landing page is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: see this https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards

Comment: Is there anyway I can get Guard to return the correct path instead of just true/false? With true/false I need to test the access of list of pages and that is not very scalable.

Comment: Nope Guards return either true if the user can access a route or false if they can’t.In case of an async call, They can also return an Observable or Promise that later on resolves to a boolean. Angular will keep the user waiting until the guard returns true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a NavigationService and put your home navigation logic there. Then inject the service in the component you want to call. By this way you don't have to repeat the logic.

Answer (score 0):

From performance point of view, Switch case statement is better than using if-else. using it in a single component e.g SecuredHome could be used in integration though.

Answer (score 0):

A few years late but I prefer a mapped solution. Makes it a little cleaner to manage the urls to check. Not sure if your `userType.Value` is an enum but you can convert it to a string if it is necessary.

```
  const routeMap = {
     TeacherUserType: '/teacher-landing/',
     StudentUserType: '/student-landing',
     AdminUserType:   '/admin-landing'
  }      

  const foundUrl = routeMap[userType.Value]

  const url = foundUrl ? foundUrl : '/login'
```